# EEPROM memory erase bit vs word

Tags: memory, eeprom, non-volatile-memory

If I have an EEPROM 1K X 16, can I erase bit by bit or just word by word (2 bytes/16 bits) in my matrix of registers ? In digital systems - TOCCI, the EEPROM is modeled by a matrix of registers, each with a flip-flop set. So the question is EEEPROM can clear just the registers, i.e a set o FFs or the memory word, or can clear bit by bit (each FF).

** note that my question don't depend on datasheet but only from the principle of building an EEPROM as a set of registers as TOCCI reference. So it's just possible to clear register-by-register (word-by-word) instead of flip-flop-by-flip-flop (bit-by-bit)

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: This question can't be answered without knowing which EEPROM is being used.

Comment: @TonyM, I added more details in. This question is from a public tender. Most of the references refer to EEPROM  as a bit-by-bit memory erasable. But it's not what it seems due to its construction principle. It may be as bit-by-bit erasable but I believe the most correct is word-by word erasable. Please, note that my question don't depend on datasheet but only from the principle of building an EEPROM as a set of registers as TOCCI reference

Comment: EEPROM is typically word erase, in your case 16 bits, but the logic could offer a bit erase... which is actually a read-modify-write, what is your question?

Comment: Thanks, @Jeroen3. You answered my question

Comment: Note that "erase by bit" isn't even meaningful.  The entire difference between an erase and a write is that erase affects a fixed block with a fixed pattern.  When the block shrinks to a single bit, the distinction ceases to matter, and the device would be called NVRAM not PROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EEEPROM can clear just the registers, i.e a set o FFs or the memory word, or can clear bit by bit (each FF).

Word by word only. To clear a bit, you must read the entire EEPROM word into RAM, erase the entire EEPROM word, change that bit in the copy in RAM, write the edited word from RAM back into the EEPROM.

Comment: If you happen to be only changing bits from 1 to 0, you can skip the erase step.